# Can i make a tips for the UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, tooltip

i want to create a UIButton.
When the user focus on this button, it will shows the tips to the user.
Can anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: What kind of focus are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to to something where if the user does a long press on a button a UIPopoverController or just a simple UIView appears with the information you want to show.  With a button you could link a method to the touchDownInside and record the time of press or start a timer that fires in a second or two.  If the timer fires the tip appears, if the user lifts their touch before then the touchUpInside method cancels the timer and performs the intended function.  Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not meant to work this way. Have a look at the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).